# Is C# namespace should be Project-Name?

Tags: c#, programming-practices, naming, namespace

I am working with multiple websites (freelancer) and a good amount of them I write using C# MVC4.

I created a very good boilerplace project that I plan to use on every next starting mvc4 application I build, however the namespace is named `Website`. I also do a lot of copy-paste from one project to another and then I always have to refactor namespaces, if I will use single namespace (Website) on all my websites then this problem dissapears.

However - will this somehow impact my application, is it considered a very bad practice?

Comment: You may take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918894/namespace-naming-conventions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The namespaces should be a little more meaningful than that. If you have some general purpose classes for processing CSV files, maybe use the namespace `Qmal.CSVUtil`. This makes it easier and less confusing to reuse that code later in other (possibly non-website) projects. You might have some other general purpose web-site related classes that could be reused in other web projects, so maybe use the namespace `Qmals.GeneralWebStuff` but something simpler such as `Qmal.Website` might actually be OK for that. Then there's the stuff that's very *project specific*, and for that you can use a namespace such as `Client3.WebProject`.